# Add New Record From Form Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, if-statement, vba, ms-access-2010, recordset

I am using a form to create invoices ("frmInvoices").  Since people sometimes send prepayments for next month invoice, I record three fields; "Prepayment Amount", "Prepayment Month", "Prepayment Year" on "frmInvoices". I am looking to place this data on the 'tblPrapayment' table as well.

The kicker.  For my system to work, I need to make sure that when the invoice form is saved and a prepayment value has been entered, that month and year are entered as well.

I have placed this code in my Microsoft Access Class Objects, not a module.  I only need this to work on the "frmInvoices" form. I don't get any errors. But nothing really happens either. If you know an easier way to do this I am open to it as well.

```
Private Sub Add_Prepayment_Save()
DoCmd.Save ("frmInvoices")
If [Rec'd_Prepayment] = "$0.00" Then
DoCmd.Save ("frmInvoices")
End If
If [Rec'd_Prepayments] <> "$0.00" And [Prepayment_Month] = "" Or [Prepayment_Year] = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please Update Prepayment Month And/Or Prepayment Year"
End If
If [Rec'd_Prepayments] <> "0.00" And [Prepayment_Month] <> "" Or [Prepayment_Year] <> "" Then
    Dim RecSet As Recordset
    Set RecSet = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblPrePayments")
    RecSet.AddNew
        RecSet![AccountID] = "AccountID"
        RecSet![Prepayment_Month] = "Billing_Month"
        RecSet![Prepayment_Year] = "Billing_Year"
        RecSet![Rec'd_Prepayment] = "Prepayment1"
    RecSet.Update
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you confirmed whether the code runs at all?  If not, set a breakpoint on the first `DoCmd.Save` and step through the code one line at a time with F8.

Comment: @HansUp I don't believe the code is running. I set a breakpoint on the DoCmd.Save and tried to step through, but nothing happened.  I couldn't any line to highlight yellow to step through. I tried adding in 'acForm' in DoCmd.Save acForm, "frmInvoices" and that didn't help either.

Comment: Smandoli's suggestion looks promising to me.  If that's not what you're looking for, tell us about how you call `Add_Prepayment_Save()` ... what is supposed to cause that code to be executed?

Comment: @HansUp I haven't tried out Smandoli's suggestion yet, but I will.  I am looking for this to be executed when the form is saved.

Comment: You have some `If` criteria with multiple clauses.  Suggest you use parenthesis to avoid unexpected order of processing for operators (And/Or).

Comment: @Smandoli I think you read my mind.  I was having an issue with this as well.  I will work with the brackets to see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your form module:

```
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
    MsgBox "Time to validate the form!"  ''reassurance, temp
    Call Add_Prepayment_Save
End Sub
```

You will probably want to make `Add_Prepayment_Save` a function that returns True or False.  If the user needs to work more on the form, the function returns false and you handle it from there.  I usually have to fiddle around a bit -- for example, calling your validation from `Form_Close` or `Form_LostFocus` may work better than `Form_AfterUpdate()`.

Comment: I haven't tried out your suggestion yet, but I will.  Thanks for the insight.  I'm still pretty new to VBA....

Comment: I tried out your idea, and it worked!  The code is running.  But I am now running into a different problem.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to edit the above and took to long. I tried out your idea, and it worked!  The code is running.  But I am now running into a different problem.  My "AccountID" is a combo box that is a number, but then shows a persons name, instead of the number. That is causing a data type conversion error. I have been scouring, and the only thing I am seeing as a possibility would be to declare "AccountID" as a Integer, and DLookup.  Any thoughts? 

Error: RecSet![AccountID] = "AccountID"

Comment: Check VBA help.  VBA requires you to reference the value in the combo box with this syntax: `Me!cboAccount.Column(1)`.  If no joy, I suggest a separate post.  I don't see context for this issue in what you've posted here and it appears unrelated.  Glad for some partial success, great job!

Comment: I think you are right now for this.  I have been poking around trying to find answers and this seems to be the common one.  I will try it out and let you know.  Thanks so much for the help!